# Why client side validation for Datetime using Jquery in not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have written JQuery code for client side validation for date. But I want to check whether the date is selected or not. If the date is selected then the message should disappear.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#StartDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#EndDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
        }
    });

});
```

.cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Start Date" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDate, "", new { @class = "error" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Finish Date" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDate, "", new { @class = "error" })
```

Model

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select start date.")]
 string StartDate { get; set; }

 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select finish date.")]
 public string EndDate { get; set; }
```

Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: Your `[Required]` attribute will do just that (assuming you have not disabled client side validation). What problems are you having?

Comment: @StephenMuecke,  If date is selected, then the message is not disappearing. So I want it to disappear if the date is selected or else it should show.

Comment: It will by default, so I assume you must have other code causing the issue. (and are you using the jQuery-UI datepicker?). And as a side note, your script for setting the min and ma values is client side only, and you really should have a `[GreaterThan]` or similar conditional validation attribute so that you get both client and server side validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes, I am using  jQuery-UI datepicker. How to do get both client and server side validation. Please help me.

Comment: You could use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan("StartDate")]` applied to your `EndDate` property. Of if you want to write your own conditional validation attributes, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I installed foolproof package from nuget and then changed string to datetime in model and also added `[GreaterThan("StartDate")]`. but still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161654/discussion-between-raj-and-stephen-muecke).